# Oracle in-memory column store is not improving SELECT query?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, in-memory-database, in-memory

I have a `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT MIN(C_PRICE), MAX(C_PRICE)
FROM CAR;
```

I run the statement and create a processing plan to look at the cost.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |     1 |     3 | 12150   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |          |     1 |     3 |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL|    CAR   |  1800K|  5273K| 12150   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I created an `inmemory` to this table `car` after setting the `inmemory` size to be 200M.

`ALTER TABLE CAR INMEMORY;`

The result

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |          |     1 |     3 | 12150   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE             |          |     1 |     3 |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS INMEMORY FULL|    CAR   |  1800K|  5273K| 12150   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is why isn't the query improved after altering the table to be in the `inmemory`? The `SELECT` statement clearly shows that it is accessing the table via `inmemory`. I thought `inmemory` creation will improve the query processing thus reducing the cost?

Comment: Cost is just an estimate, and only includes enough information for Oracle to determine the best execution plan. What is the actual difference in execution time? If you really wanted to make this query fast, you would index the aggregated column and split it up into two scalar subqueries (one to do min, one to do max)

Comment: @Sunny J -
what is your overall experience with inmemory  column store , if you can share would be great help I am planning to use it for my OLAP scenarios

Comment: downvoted as the author is not interested to get an answer and it leads to make this question useless

Comment: @AndrewSayer, why any additional indexes are needed if we have already a colum store which one should extemally quickly resolve max\min for any columns?

Answer (score 1):

Two things you should look at. One, is the table populated in the IM column store (i.e. v$im_segments)? Second, what was the time difference between the two queries and where was the time spent? SQL Monitor active reports are excellent for determining this.